# Firestore UPDATE a single field but creates another node

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am updating a single field name, which is "name", I am successful on editing it, but it creates another node. like this [image: I only want it to be Name: "Christian" not Name: "Name": "Christian"]

This is my **Code:**

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let uid;
    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid);
      docRef.update({
        name,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('Profile Successfully Edited!');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error updating the document:', error);
      })
    }
```

Comment: What is name? In update

Comment: its the field name I want to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already found the solution,

```
if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      db.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
        name })....
```

I just directly put the .update unto the db reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
docRef.update({
    name:"Christian",
    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

You can pass a string var after `name:`